# Registration with second database generated by make:registration-form- Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Stack**
Symfony 5

**What i need to do?**

I have to make a registratrion form that will store data in a second database.

**How i need to do this?**

With *make:registration-form* command

**What's the problem?**

Even if a setted my entity manager on my second database, the repository try to store data in the first database

**Explication**

I'm stuck in this error on Symfony 5, because the entity manager try to save data in the first DB, but it should do this in the second one!

***"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'en_manager_live.User' doesn't exist"***

I use two database (with docker), and i think i have correctly configured the second database in doctrine.yaml (called simply "second"):

```
    doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            second:

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_SECOND_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4

    orm:
            default_entity_manager: default
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    connection: default
                    mappings:
                        Main:
                            is_bundle: false
                            type: annotation
                            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                            prefix: 'App\Entity'
                            alias: Main
                second:
                    connection: second
                    mappings:
                        second:
                            is_bundle: false
                            type: annotation
                            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                            prefix: 'App\Entity'
                            alias: Second
when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system
```

So if i check the server parameters in the profiler, i get my second DB:

[image]

Now, all should be setted. So i execute the command make:registration-form and i get my form **RegistrationFormType**:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'entityManager' => 'second',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is my **UserRepository**:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<User>
 *
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function add(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function upgradePassword(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newHashedPassword);

        $this->add($user, true);
    }

}
```

But when i fill the form and save, the repositry try to save data in the FIRST database (and doesn't find the correct table) so i get the error.

**What i try to do**

According to [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) , i can handler two entity manager putting in the parameter of getManager(), the name of second database that in my case is "second.".
So i replace first one, the extension ServiceEntityRepository to EntityReporitory and in the constructor, i give it the correct entity manager in this way:

```
    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{
    private $em;
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $this->em = $registry->getManager('second');

    }
```

But obviously, i get this error:

***Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\UserRepository::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\en-manager-official\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory.php on line 90***

Also i tried to use the ManagerRegistry in every function, but i still get errors.

What i should do? Thank you!

Comment: You are sort of on the right track but for all intents and purposes, Symfony's implementation of having the entity type managed by multiple entities is broken.  You discovered the first issue which is the ServiceEntityRepository.  The next issue is the ContainerRepositoryFactory which pulls repositories from the container is they exist which means you always get the same repository regardless of the entity manager.   So you need to prevent your repositories being defined as services and use Doctrine's RepositoryFactory.  Which in turn can cause even more fun.

Comment: Bottom line: don't try to map the same entity types to multiple entity managers.  Make a User type specifically for the second entity manager.

Comment: I found a solution (i think), but i don't know if is a correct solution . [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9878)

Comment: If you are talking about the solution at the very end of the rather lengthy discussion then yes, it should work for you.  It better since I'm the one that wrote it.  But let us know if you run into additional problems.  There always seems to be something which is why not doing this sort of thing in the first place is the recommended approach.

Comment: Ehy ! For now all is working. I will let open this discussione for un week, i ll test the app and i keep u update ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your doctrine.yaml file, try to add your second database information before the first one. Something like that:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        second:
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_SECOND_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
        default:
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4

orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            second:
                connection: second
                mappings:
                    second:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Second
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Main
```

I am not sure about that, but I used to do that when I have so many providers in my security file and it works well.

Comment: All that does is change the order of the entity managers in the registry which means that your repositories will always be linked to the 'second' entity manager instead of 'default'.  Does not fix the underlying issues.